# AJAX button with success callback. (Titan Framework)

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wp-admin

I'm creating a plugin with [Titan Framework](http://www.titanframework.net/) to handle the options pages. As part of the plugin, I collect a log of failed log-in attempts to WP and then display them in the options panel.

Every so often the log needs clearing out and so I have created an [AJAX Button](http://www.titanframework.net/docs/ajax-button/) control that when clicked calls a function that wipes the log. However, inorder to show this process has taken place and that pressing the button actually did something, I need to refresh the page.

According to the documentation for Titan Framework it would appear that this can be done using the call back property of the button. It says:

> success_callback | string/array | (Optional) The name of a Javascript function (within the scope of window) to call after a successful ajax call. Use admin_enqueue_scripts to add your scripts. Defaults to blank/none.

However there are no examples showing how this is actually done. Here's my code so far:

PLUGIN FILE(AJAX button):

```
$lsPanel->createOption( array(
  'name' => 'Reset Log',
  'type' => 'ajax-button',
  'action' => 'yyy_reset_security_logs',
  'label' => __( 'Reset Security Logs', 'default' ),
  'success_callback' => 'ajax_success_refresh',
) );

//run a clinical cms / titan framework ajax call
add_action( 'wp_ajax_yyy_reset_security_logs', array( $this, 'yyy_reset_logs' ) );
```

PLUGIN FILE(AJAX action function):

```
function yyy_reset_logs() {
    $result = $this->yyy_clear_security_logs();
    if ( $result ) {
        wp_send_json_success( __( 'Success!', 'default' ) );
        }
        wp_send_json_error( __( 'Failed!', 'default' ) );
    }
```

So now I want to refresh the page using a success callback. I've enqueued a simple script via ***admin_enqueue_scripts*** :

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

The goal is to have this script refresh the page but only when the AJAX button is pressed and a success result is detected. At present, the script is loaded onloading any/all admin pages. The result being that admin pages never load fully due to an infinite JavaScript loop.

Any ideas how I can limit the refresh JS to only be run on a successful clearing of the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now I want to refresh the page using a success callback. I've
>   enqueued a simple script via ***admin_enqueue_scripts***:

I believe in that script, you need a global JS `function` named `ajax_success_refresh`, as in the following example:

```
// This is the 'success_callback' for the AJAX action of 'yyy_reset_security_logs'.
function ajax_success_refresh() {
    window.location.reload( false );
}
```

*Hint:* Since it's a global `function`, you should make the function name as unique as possible.